# How does order by position clause work in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**query 1**

```
select Name from Country order by IF(Code IN ("USA","AFG","IND"),1,2),Name LIMIT 10
```

**query2**

```
select Name from Country order by 2 , Name LIMIT 10 ;
```

Query2 is giving error as i am trying to sort the result set on the basis of **2nd position** but there is only one column in the result Set. **[Expected]**

query1 is working fine for all cases . As per my understanding of IF clause it returns first parameter if condition is fulfilled otherwise returns 2nd parameter .

Query1 should work fine for CODE in set ("USA","AFG","IND") because IF will return 1 and condition would be **order by 1,name** .

For all **other CODES**, condition would be **order by 2 , Name** and **it is similar to query2** But it is still executing .

**why this case is getting successfully executed in spite of the fact that its condition is wrong .(order by 2,name) ?**

**Result Set for Query 1**

```
+----------------+
| Name           |
+----------------+
| Afghanistan    |
| India          |
| United States  |
| Albania        |
| Algeria        |
| American Samoa |
| Andorra        |
| Angola         |
| Anguilla       |
| Antarctica     |
+----------------+
```

**Second Example**

```
mysql> SELECT Name from Country ORDER BY
-> CASE code
-> WHEN "USA" THEN 1
-> WHEN "IND" THEN 2
-> WHEN "AFG" THEN 3
-> ELSE 4 END,Name LIMIT 10 ;
```

This query is also generating a different position for each specific code . How will this be executed ?

Comment: is 1 and 2 are your table column name??

Comment: They are positions of columns and there is no 2nd position in my result set .

Comment: What is the **end result** you want?  If you want countries with codes `"USA", "AFG", "IND"` to be first, then everybody else, it does that.  Of course, it'll ignore indices due to the `IF` in the `ORDER BY` - if you define a temp/inline table it's more likely to be able to use an index (although as a table of countries is relatively small, it may not matter anyways).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : purpose was to get these countries above all in listings . I was not able to understand the difference between query1 and query2 .
query1 is executing and query2 is failing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you had:

```
ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn
```

And the *values* that `SomeOtherColumn` contained happened to be a mixture of 2s and 3s. Do you think the server will somehow find a way to sort the results based on the second and third columns? Or will it just sort those numbers?

There's a difference between `ORDER BY <literal number>` and `ORDER BY <expression that happens to return numbers>`.

So the first query isn't, in any way, using a "positional" `ORDER BY` clause.

---

Imagine your data looked like this:

```
Name           Code           Froogal
Albania        ALB            2
Algeria        DZA            2
Afghanistan    AFG            1
American Samoa ASM            2
Andorra        AND            2
India          IND            1
Angola         AGO            2
Anguilla       AIA            2
Antarctica     ATA            2
United States  USA            1
```

And you had written query 1 as:

```
select Name from Country order by Froogal,Name LIMIT 10
```

Would you still be surprised at the result set, or expect an error?

Comment: Is it just a way to  satisfy server to not throw any error ?
Is sort working when we are getting the order by 1,Name condition from our expression ?

Comment: @Learner - I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: How does the order by with Expression works ?
Is there some specific rules regarding this ?

Comment: @Learner - no special rules - for each row, the expression is evaluated to produce *values*.

Comment: mysql> SELECT Name from Country ORDER BY
    -> CASE code
    -> WHEN "USA" THEN 1
    -> WHEN "IND" THEN 2
    -> WHEN "AFG" THEN 3
    -> ELSE 4 END,Name LIMIT 10 ;

How this query will get executed as its generating a differeny number for each condition .

Comment: @Learner - again, just imagine that instead of that `CASE` expression, you had another column in your table containing the results of evaluating that condition. I don't understand your continued confusion on this. The expression is evaluated for each row and then those values are sorted. The only time things change is when there is a *literal* number in the order by clause. Then, and only then, is that number the ordinal position of a column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results to be sorted either on column 1 or 2, then just supply those column names. The only thing you need to worry about is that the columns need to be of the same type, or can be casted as the same type.

```
select Name, OtherName from Country order by IF(Code IN ("USA","AFG","IND"),Name,OtherName), Name LIMIT 10

-- PS> You dont need to select the `OtherColumn` for the order by to work
```

Keep in mind though that using functions and casting in an order by is VERY SLOW. Since you called the table country I'm going to assume there are countries in the table so only a very limited number of records. In that case it will be slower, but in most cases manageable.

Never use this approach on a table with many records.